# Unknown format file in MSNOISE

Tags: python, format

A question about MSNoise. I am trying to read my data with **msnoise scan_archive** but I get the next message.

> Blockquote

2023-07-10 20:19:06.070562 msnoise [pid 9640][ERROR]: Error while processing file 'C:\mypath\db.ini': Unknown format for file C:\mypath\db.ini

2023-07-10 20:19:06.074551 msnoise [pid 9640][ERROR]: Error while processing file 'C:\mypath\msnoise.sqlite': Unknown format for file

> Blockquote

All requested is already installed!

I would appreciate some help here :)